# ios7 click and hover not working

Tags: javascript, css, iphone, ipad, click

I have this problem on this website: http://www.gruppoedico.it/Default.aspx
The top menu has some dropdown functionality (on "Gruppo", "Attività", "Videoguide" and "Contatti"). It works like a charm on every browser exept the ones on ios7 (maybe ios6 too, I haven't tried), where the menu works on the page I linked, but not on every other page of the menu (you can try it just navigating on one of the pages from the menu).

I tried using the hover effect of css (no-js) and got the same result. Actually i'm using this script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("nav li").click(function () {
                $(".hover").removeClass('hover');
                if ($(this).find("ul").hasClass('hover')) {
                    $(this).find("ul").removeClass('hover');
                } else {
                    $(this).find("ul").addClass('hover');
                }
            });
        });
```

I'm experiencing this problem only on apple devices.

**UPDATE**
I think i found the problem, it's the transition on the ul that in some way interfer with the click event. I'll try to find a solution.

Comment: Your code makes NO sense. You are removing the class hover from all elements than toggling it. There is nothing to toggle.

Comment: are you trying to get this to work on safari on iOS? wasn't totally clear.

Comment: @epascarello yeah i know, that's the result of something like 2 hours of try. The problem is that the menu DON'T show up on the pages!

Comment: @azochz i have this problem on safari and chrome on both ipad and iphone.

Comment: My best guess then is you have found a loophole in how jquery can be used on iOS. I don't think this is an issue with CSS on iOS (i.e. transitioning from hidden to not hidden).Is this script in the body of your document, or is it being linked to? Maybe putting it in the body of your doc would be something to try.